# BitBake -- Variable expansion problem & the most efficient way of reading BitBake source files

Tags: bitbake

In the official bitbake documentation there is an example for immediate expansion ([here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#immediate-variable-expansion)) that practically states:

> In this example:
>
> ```
> T = "123"
> A := "test ${T}"
> T = "456"
> B := "${T} ${C}"
> C = "cval"
> C := "${C}append"
> ```
>
> At the end we get these values:
>
> - A contains `test 123`,
> - T contains `456`
> - B contains `456 cvalappend`
> - C contains `cvalappend`.

But same official documentation also states ([source](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#variable-expansion), last paragraph):

> If the variable expansion syntax is used on a variable that does not
> exist, the string is kept as is. For example, given the following
> assignment, `BAR` expands to the literal string `${FOO}` as long as `FOO`
> does not exist.
>
> ```
> BAR = "${FOO}"
> ```

And this is why to me all the values from the first cited block seem reasonable except for `B` which in my opinion should contain `456 ${C}`.

But official documentation does give a brief explanation:

> This is because references to undefined variables are preserved as is
> during (immediate)expansion.

**A: And I don't understand this explanation. Can anyone help me understand?**

This all is just a part of a bigger problem... In fact, I don't even know, how to properly read BitBake source files, where some variables/overrides are assigned immediately, some variables/overrides are assigned when variable is used and some are assigned after an entire file is parsed i.e. anonymous functions.

This is a one big confusion... Currently I am doubting if it is even possible to normally read a source file line by line? Should I instead first search for all the immediate operations (`:=`, `+=`, `=+`, `.=`, `=.`) and read only those lines and then re-read an netire source file ommiting anonymous functions, and then re-read an entire source file and then only read anonymous functions. And synthesize all in my head at the end? My brain RAM is limited you know... So...

**B: What is the most efficient way to read Bitbake source files?**

Answer (score 0):

The value of `B` after the immediate expansion is `456 ${C}`, i.e. the value of `C` isn't set so it is just just left unexpanded.

After `C` is set a few lines later, rather than a value of `456 ${C}`, it becomes `456 cvalappend` since `C` now has a value. If you deleted the value of `C`, it would become `456 ${C}` again but if you delete `${T}` it would remain unchanged as the value of `T` is now hardcoded into `B`.

The *"At the end"* means after all those statements, you're just thinking of the value after `B` is set but not `C`.

The most efficient way to parse bitbake source files is to let bitbake itself do it, it is what it is designed for!

Comment: How can program even set `B` to `456 cvalappend`? Is source file re-read multiple times?

Comment: It isn't set to it, the value is expanded to that when the variable is read.

Comment: But it must be read two times it seems... Because first time it is read it evaluates to `456 ${C}`, because at that time `C` is not yet set.  How does this mechanism work exactly?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be read twice. The code doesn't immediately expand by default, it just stores in the datastore. Immediate expansion is possible but only when specifically requested and almost all expansion is deferred.